# Remove blank lines from json

Tags: html, jquery, json

I have literally no idea what I am doing. I managed to got this snippet together by copy & pasting:

```
$(function () {

$.ajax({
    url: "json url",
    success: function (result) {
        
        $.each(result, function (index, item) {
            $(".PostEntries").append("<div class='col-lg-4 mb-3 d-flex align-items-stretch' style='float:left'><div class='card'><img src="+item.picturePath+" class='card-img-top'>" +
                                            "<div class='card-body'>" + "<small class='text-muted text-start'>Posted:" +item.Date_Created + "</small>" +
                                            "<h5 class='card-title'>"+item.Article_Title+"</h5>" +
                                            "<p class='card-text text-muted'>"+item.Blog_Entry_Text+"</p>" + "<img src="+item.PictureGallery_1+" width='60px'>" +
                                          "</div>" +
                                        "</div>" + "</div>" + 
                                    "</div>");
        });
        
        
        

    }

    
    
});
```

this is what the json url calls:

```
    "Importance_Index": "0",
    "ID": 24,
    "Date_Created": "19/10/2022",
    "Date_Last_Modified": "19/10/2022",
    "Article_Title": "Some Title",
    "Blog_Entry_Text": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    "picturePath": "image.jpg",
    "PictureGallery_1": "gallery-image.jpg",
    "PictureGallery_2": "",
    "PictureGallery_3": "",
    "PictureGallery_4": "",
    "URL_Video": "",
    "URL": "some link"
}, {
    "Importance_Index": "0",
    "ID": 2,
    "Date_Created": "24/06/2021",
    "Date_Last_Modified": "02/12/2021",
    "Article_Title": "Some Title",
    "Blog_Entry_Text": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    "picturePath": "image.jpg",
    "PictureGallery_1": "",
    "PictureGallery_2": "",
    "PictureGallery_3": "",
    "PictureGallery_4": "",
    "URL_Video": "",
    "URL": ""
},
```

The question here is how can I stop empty lines in the json from displaying. Not every article has an image or gallery. Currently the all posts without gallery images are displaying blue questions marks for missing images on my html.
I am sure there is a way to skip empty json entries from displaying.

As I said I know nothing about this and would appreciate your help.
Many Thanks in advance,
Heiko

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a').filter(function(){return $(this).attr('href') === "" || $(this).attr('href') === "%"}).hide();

// Or, hide them
$("img").on("error", function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

So, I found a work around myself. The first simply removes links that are blank or have in my case a "%" symbol (I added the % on every empty value). I tried the "#" but that would have removed parts of my navigation, specifically the drop-down menus.
The 2nd one just hides dead images.
This seems to be working but I was hoping to find a more elegant solution.